# Using XMLHttpRequest, reading XML data

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to read the xml file but somehow i am getting this error: Invalid number of parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[ 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else { 
        // code for IE6, IE5 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "employee.XML", false); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

    var empid= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("empid"); 
    var total = placeMarks.length; 
    var names = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name"); 
    var designation= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("designation"); 
    var phone= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("phone"); 
    ..... 
</script>
```

XML data:

```
<employee>
<emp id="1007">
<name>John Chamber</name>
<designation>Web Expert1</designation>
<phone>555-55-555</phone>
<name>John D</name>
<designation>Web123123</designation>
<phone>555-55-555</phone>
<name>Chamber</name>
<designation>Web Expert</designation>
<phone>555-55-555</phone>
<name>Thomas</name>
<designation>TESTTEST</designation>
<phone>555-55-555</phone>

</emp>
</employee>
```

Comment: In which browser(s) do you get the error? Where is `placeMarks` defined?

Comment: Wow, nothing like deleting comments. Especially my one that asked for more details. I love people editing and not paying attention.

Comment: Lets do this again. What browser? What is the full Error Message? What is the line number?

Comment: You are not getting errors that how can you say `i am getting this error: Invalid number of parameters.` Sounds like you are getting an error. :)

Comment: hi....can any one guide me how to read the "employee.XML" if its onserver..

Comment: You should not use `false` for the third (async) argument to `xmlhttp.open`.  Your users will hate you.  Use `xmlhttp.onload = function() { ... };` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly branch out your code as shown below to see if the server is responding with the correct `200` response.

```
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "employee.XML", false); 
            xmlhttp.send(null);
         if (xmlhttp.status==200) {

                      xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
                     var empid= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("emp"); 
                     var total = placeMarks.length; 
                     var names = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name"); 
                     var designation= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("designation"); 
                     var phone= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("phone"); 
                     ..... ;
          }

                else if (xmlhttp.status==404) {
          alert("XML could not be found");
         }
```

Also my suggestion is to use a javascript library like jQuery which does much of the heavy lifting for your. The whole code for creating the XHR object simply reduces to one line

```
$.get(url,function(data){
                     xmlDoc = data; 
                     var empid= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("emp"); 
                     var total = placeMarks.length; 
                     var names = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name"); 
                     var designation= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("designation"); 
                     var phone= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("phone");
});
```

Finally whichever modern browser that you are using should easily be able to point out which line in the script is throwing the error. If you still face the issue please confirm which line is throwing the error.

**EDIT**
The problem scope has changed. The OP now wants to loop through the xml.
First of all the xml needs to be designed keeping the requirements in mind. Hence it should look like this

```
<employees>
 <emp id="006">
   <name>John Chamber</name>
   <designation>Web Expert1</designation>
   <phone>555-55-555</phone>
 </emp>
 <emp id="007"> 
  <name>John D</name>
  <designation>Web123123</designation>
  <phone>555-55-555</phone>
 </emp>
 <emp id="008"> 
  <name>Chamber</name>
  <designation>Web Expert</designation>
  <phone>555-55-555</phone>
 </emp>
 <emp id="009">
   <name>Thomas</name>
   <designation>TESTTEST</designation>
   <phone>555-55-555</phone>
 </emp>
</employees>
```

**Now the javascript for parsing the xml**

```
var emp=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("emp");
for (i=0;i<emp.length;i++) {
   var names=emp[i].childNodes[0].text;
   var designation= emp[i].childNodes[1].text;
   ......
}
```

Comment: Philar: how would you loop in `xmlhttp.open("GET"`

Comment: Chicagoland, I think the mistake that you are making is that the xml tag should be `<emp id="1007">` not `<empid="1007">`. Hence while parsing it should be `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("emp")`

Comment: After making this change if you need the value of the attribute `id` you should use `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("emp")[0].attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue`

Comment: Thanks Philar: but how do i loop through the xml file; i will update the xml file to get you an idea what i am talking about.

Comment: i have just updated the `xml` file what i want to do is to loop throught the xml file and grab the values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xmlhttp.send(null);` http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method